# How to use regex to find and replace a specific text?

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have the following code to replace the value between "-sav" and "test"

```
test="-val https://www.randomurl.com -sav 1aFAd381cCCb86FD300e7a3A399a6014.test -speed 2 -save -delay 14"

test=$(sed 's/-sav *.*\./-sav 12345./g' <<< $test)

echo $test

# -val https://www.randomurl.com -sav 12345.test -speed 2 -save -delay 14
```

How do I also include what is before -speed 2. Expected new variable value could be.

```
test="-val https://www.randomurl.com -sav 12345.itWorks -speed 2 -save -delay 14"
```

Comment: There's no need to write `<space>*` before `.*`, since the spaces will be included in `.*`.

Comment: What should the result be for the second version?

Comment: Try `sed -E 's/-sav *(.*)(\.[^ ]*)/-sav (\1 12345\2)/g'`

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 use bash arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following `sed` code. Have applied `-E` flag to enable ERE(extended regular expression) with `sed` program here and where `test` is OP's mentioned shell variable.

```
echo "$test" | sed -E 's/(^-.*sav )[^.]*\.[^ ]*(.*)/-sav (\1 12345.itworks\2)/g'
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be, passing `echo` command's output as standard input to `sed` command. In `sed` program using regex `(^-.*sav )[^.]*\.[^ ]*(.*)`, which creates 2 capturing groups in matching regex portion and then while substituting it using these 2 capturing groups(1st and 2nd one) along with newly required value `12355` as per OP's requirement.

***NOTE:*** I am using `g` flag here with `sed` to perform substitution Globally in case you have only 1 match in your variable then remove it.

Comment: The output I receive is  "-val https://www.randomurl.com -sav (1aFAd381cCCb86FD300e7a3A399a6014 12345.test) -speed 2 -save -delay 14". So not exactly what I was looking for

Comment: @Sstack324, this is how it looks in your shown samples in your question, please do update your question with samples output more clearly so that we could help.

Comment: @Sstack324, I have edited my solution, please do check it once and let me know how it goes.